# new at using for loops

Tags: for-loop, go

All of the comments I received recommended this

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func getWord(word string) string {
    value:=[]rune(word)
    for i := 0; i < len(word); i++ {
        j := i + 1
        fmt.Println("positions", i, j)
    }
}
```

but when I want to subtract the values in the 2 positions

```
if value[i] - value[j] == 0 || value[i] - value[j] == 1 {
    return value
} else {
    return " "
}
```

these are the output instead

```
0 1
panic: runtime error: index out of range

goroutine 1 [running]:
```

https://play.golang.org/p/VAW6AhB1lev

Comment: You don't need 2 loops for that - create one loop and output the `i` and `i + 1` pairs.

Comment: read here about loops , https://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/Looping/NestedFor.htm

Comment: @zerkms i did that but, i couldn't get this code to work

`````
if dictionary[position1]-dictionary[position2]==0 || dictionary[position1]-dictionary[position2]==1 {
                return dictionary
                }else{
                    return " "
                }

Comment: @strawberrylatte you need to explain your **actual** problem in details then. For what you posted in the question, you just need a single loop and `i` and `i + 1`.

Comment: @zerkms see my edits

Comment: @strawberrylatte could you provide complete code that we could run on https://play.golang.org/ and that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: at least on the latest iteration `j` goes out of index range

Comment: @zerkms https://play.golang.org/p/VAW6AhB1lev

Comment: Don't mutate your questions like that. This invalidates existing answers.

Comment: @strawberrylatte your play does not panic

Answer (score 3):

Your second for loop runs through all iterations blocking the first until it completes.

This is why i prints 1 until j reaches 10

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
   printf("positions %d %d\n", i, i+1);
}
```

Comment: i edited my codes according to your suggestion, but i encounter more problems, see my edits @Isaac Reed